# Cannot draw on bottom or right side of a fullscreen form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, graphics

I have the code below that is supposed to draw lines from the top to the bottom of a fullscreen form.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Graphics g;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            g = CreateGraphics();
        }

        private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black);
            for (int i = 0; i < this.ClientSize.Height; i++)
            {
                g.DrawLine(pen, 100, i, 50, i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The form in question (Form1) is maximized, borderless and topmost. Result of the code is, form is displayed, lines are drawn one after another but when the number i of the loop reaches 1055 DrawLine starts not working and until the end of the loop from then on notghing else is drawn, therefore there is a blank space at the bottom of the form.

**some extra information**

My desktop resolution is 1920 x 1080

this.Size = 1920 x 1080

this.ClientSize = 1920 x 1080

Anyone is welcomed to create an empty project, set form properties (maximized, topmost, borderless) and copy-paste this code to reproduce the problem I have.

Comment: Does your form have a title bar?

Comment: Looks like the ShowWindow() trick played a trick on you instead.  There's no need, a borderless maximized window already overlaps the taskbar.

Comment: but without that trick i have the same problem

Comment: Where is the drawing code - is it in the OnPaint event?

Comment: yes, it is done in a function called from Paint event

Comment: I can't reproduce it.  Any chance you could send me the code?  win8128 at aol.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot. BTW I just tried reproducing in a new empty project and i did. http://pastebin.com/igqPNKkq Here client height is 1080, my screen resolution is also 1920 x 1080 but same thing happens

Comment: Edited my answer with a solution following your code sample but seems I got pipped to the post by two others. Just goes to show the importance of phrasing a question right with code examples. As soon as you put that code sample up you got your answer! Anyway best of luck, glad you found a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's fixed code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication4
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
//         Graphics g;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
//            g = CreateGraphics();
        }

        private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black);
            for (int i = 0; i < this.ClientSize.Height; i++)
            {
   //             g.DrawLine(pen, 100, i, 50, i);
                e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, 100, i, 50, i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The graphics object is meant to be used right away and then disposed. The main reason is, there is a real windows Device Context (HDC) that is used by the graphics object. This is a limited resource, and if you tie up too many in the program windows will cut the program off. If you have too many programs using too many, you'll actually crash windows' UI, or at least parts of it, although each subsequent version of windows adds protections to prevent this. Disposing the HDC *explicitly* and immediately with .Dispose or the using construct, when you're done drawing, is required; by the time the GC gets around to it, you could have used them all up.

The framework will create the Graphics and Dispose of it for you in the paint event. So when you're drawing in paint (recommended), you don't have to dispose the graphics.

Any time you use creategraphics on a form, or Graphics.FromImage or similar, you should use it and dispose of it ASAP.

Because of this design and the requirements that go with it, the HDC makes assumptions about the window at the moment it is grabbed. In the interem, the window could maximize or resize itself before drawing on it occurs again. The paint event also grabs another one from the same window handle - an unusual usage of HDC - so it is probably one of these issues which is causing the strange behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the `e.Graphics` from your Paint event instead of the `CreateGraphics()` method.

Example:

```
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) {

  // using your CreateGraphics:
  Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black);
  for (int i = 0; i < this.ClientSize.Height; i++) {
    g.DrawLine(pen, 100, i, 50, i);
  }

  // using e.Graphics:
  for (int i = 0; i < this.ClientSize.Height; i++) {
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, 200, i, 250, i);
  }

}
```

Difference:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

as far as I'm aware Windows Forms graphics coordinates are y=0 (topmost edge) to Height-1 (bottommost edge) in the Y-direction and x=0 (leftmost edge) to Width-1 (rightmost edge) in the X direction.

if this is so the first example will not work, as you are drawing solely outside the viewable area, however the second example will as you are drawing a vertical line that only draws one pixel outside of the viewable area.

Try changing to 1079 and see if it renders. Failing that, try incrementing y in the first example and find out where it stops. Do you have some Form Chrome to take into account? For instance a windows form Form with height = 1080 might use 20 pixels on the title bar and bottom edge, so the actual viewable area may be smaller.

**Edit 1**

Edited following your code addition to the question. I modified the code as follows and it draws a perfect rectangle on my system. Just out of interest, why are you creating a graphics object in the constructor of the form? You should use the one provided by the paint event args. The Graphics object will be created and disposed of by the .NET Runtime every time the form is repainted.

Also I added a resize event handler to repaint the form. Without this when you resize it doesnt set the rectangle to the new form size.

Can you test this and tell me if you get the same problem? Also what other properties am I missing (ie: Form.Borderstyle etc) to get the same issue as you?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(Form1_Paint);
        this.Resize += new EventHandler(Form1_Resize);
    }

    void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Invalidate(true);
    }

    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 2.0f))
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, new Rectangle(0, 0, ClientSize.Width-1, ClientSize.Height-1));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I will try but 1079 but i think the area which is not drawn is far more than just 1 pixel on the bottom.

about chorme, form does not have anything (titlebar, etc...)

Comment: i've just edited the question, form starts drawing after pixel number is less than / equal to 1055

Comment: So, what's the range of Y coordinates that results in successful drawing? From your comment above it sounds like Y > 1055, did you mean 0 <= Y <= 1055?

Comment: Ok got it, I commented before seeing your edit. Ok now stick debug logging in your form resize and the top few user controls to output size and client size. Which of them has a height of 1055? Out of interest if you draw a rectangle of height 1055 does it touch both top and bottom edges? Finally if you include a constant, height-25, then change the resolution or resize does it still draw to the top and bottom edge?

Comment: what do you mean by stick debug logging in?

Comment: For instance, add code similar to the following inside the Resized event of your form and controls. this will help you determine the sizes of all controls and find out which ones have a client size that matches your drawable area:  "Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Size = {0},{1}. ClientSize= {2},{3}", this.Size.Width, this.Size.Height, this.ClientSize.Width, this.ClientSize.Height));

Comment: I've put the code into ResizeEnd event and a breakpoint on it, but it is never hit. By the way, the only control is form itself and it's client area is 1920 x 1080

Comment: when i draw a rectangle with DrawRectangle(pen, 0, 0, width, 1080) i cannot see the bottom of the rectangle...

Comment: Did you try putting a usercontrol on the form and drawing to that? By the way, if you want me or anyone else to look into this consider revising your question and posting a code example. Regards,

Comment: No I haven't tried it. What kind of control can be used to test it? I guess not a button. About your advice, I will take it and edit the question further

Comment: any control, just create a new class that inherits from UserControl then override OnPaint inside that. Place the custom control class on your form with DockStyle.Fill. Is there any difference? To be honest in the past I have seen an issue like this and I've just put a constant number of pixels to offset the reported height. This was due to window chrome however which as you say is not there in your example.

Really stupid question. If you hit "Printscreen" while your app is up and you then paste the screenshot into Paint.Net (or similar) how many pixels high is the client area of the form?